# Autofocus to input field when user submit empty or wrong form in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I m trying to autofocus on field when user submit empty or wrong data means compare  to regex i have defined in code 
my php code is here

```html
if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
    $passwordErr = "Name is required";
 $_POST["password"].focus();
  } else {
    $password  = test_input($_POST["password"]);
     }
```

plz guide me to solve this issue thanks

Comment: You need to do this with JavaScript. So something like `echo '<script>document.getElementById("password").focus();</script>'` assuming your password field has an id of password.

Comment: @Dave Chen bro can it possible through php?

Comment: @ArSeN bro its simple english auto focus on on empty textfield when user click on submit button

Comment: Uhh what you could do is add an `autofocus` attribute to the input element, that's one way to avoid using JavaScript, but no, there's no way to do this with only PHP.

Comment: @Dave Chen yeah bro i already add that but not  good approach

Comment: Not a good approach because it doesn't work or because you don't like it? You should provide more information. The facts are this: You cannot use PHP alone to control client side focus states, you can either use HTML5's autofocus attribute or JavaScript to focus it with a script. Those are your two options, pick one.

Comment: @Dave Chen means user html autofocus attribute is not good enough coz it can only focus us on start but when error occur or user enter invalid data than it may not support us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$_POST["password"]` stands for `read input variable 'password'` on server. It has no relation to the input field in the browser window.

If you want to focus the input field it has to be done on client side. This means some JavaScript has to validate the result of the AJAX call (if you used one to send the request) or you have to echo the JavaScript code (like suggested by @Dave Chen).

Comment: Ok Brother Better with AJAX but i want to learn it also through php Bcoz all validation i applied in PHP